# rsuite date range picker -- Remove 'X' cancel from the rsuite rangeDatepicker

Tags: reactjs, date, daterangepicker, rsuite

I am using rsuite Daterangepicker I want to remove the cancel or 'x' button from it after the date is selected as I don't want the value to be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the prop `cleanable` to `false`:

```
< DateRangePicker cleanable={false} />
```

Comment: if this content is a part of the question, use the edit button under your original question and add this content to it. if it's an answer, Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.